# Wall supply transition to a 2nd wall supply

Tags: power-supply

A device has various supply rails, but they are all derived from one 9V wall supply via switcher and linears.  What kind of issues can occur if the device is unplugged from one wall supply and then plugged in another, within seconds?

Are the grounds of the two equivalent or can weird reverse biasing happen momentarily; especially if the ground or power terminal of the 2nd supply doesn't connect simultaneously?

Is there some terminology that I am missing that could help in searches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There should be no issues with reversals.  The circuit may stop to function because there may not be sufficient hold time on teh charge storage on board.  or some of the rails may droop whilst others are held.  This may be more problematic in certain cases with parts of the circuit having gone through a reset whilst other parts are in an old state.  without knowing what the circuit is and it' very hard to tell.  "Hold time", "brown out sensitivity", "rail sag", "Rail droop" or "power droop" to name a few searches.